# Update a part of column value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a database in SQL Server with its data. I need change a part of some columns value in some conditions.

Imagine the value as "**0010020001**".
**002** belongs to another value in my database and whenever I want to change it to **005**, I must update the previous 10-digits code to "**001005001**".

Actually, I need to update just a part of columns value using `UPDATE` statement. How can I do it (in this example)?

Comment: You should store this information in separate columns then it will be trivial. You can have a non persisted computed column that does the concatenation together.

Comment: Can I use SUBSTRING function in TSQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While everyone else is correct that if you have control of the schema you should definitely not store your data this way, this is how I would solve the issue you as you described it if I couldn't adjust the schema.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#test') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #test

create table #test
(
id int,
multivaluecolumn varchar(20)
)

insert #Test
select 1,'001002001'
UNION
select 2,'002004002'
UNION
select 3,'003006003'
GO

declare @oldmiddlevalue char(3) 
set @oldmiddlevalue= '002'
declare @newmiddlevalue char(3)
set @newmiddlevalue = '005'

select * from #Test

Update #Test set multivaluecolumn =left(multivaluecolumn,3) + @newmiddlevalue + right(multivaluecolumn,3)
where substring(multivaluecolumn,4,3) = @oldmiddlevalue


select * from #Test
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use CSV(comma separated values) or use any other symbol like ~ to store tha values. Once you need to update a part of it use php explode function and then update it. After your work is done, concat all the values again to get the desired string to be stored in your column.

In that case your column will have values VARCHAR like 001~002~0001

Comment: Use any separator of your wish to separate the values

Comment: When u need to use the entire 10 digits, you can retrieve the original 10 digit string by concating and converting into integer(typecasting)